# Read / Write custom file android

Tags: android, io

In my application I have to create 4 .dat files to store some information for my app. But I have to change them in my app in "settings activity".

I created them in raw catalog:
    /raw/1.txt
    /raw/2.txt
    /raw/3.txt
    /raw/4.txt

I can read them but i can't write them.

So, where i can store a simple dat file that can be modified.

Answer (score 1):

You can't write to files located in the `res/raw`-folder because those files are static.

Instead, you could use the "Internal Storage", as illustrated [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal).

Answer (score 0):

I would use the phone's internal storage. [This](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal) reference gives examples of reading and writing.